# En un servidor SSH en linux como se puede hacer para que el servidor imprima la fecha y hora del último acceso efectuado por el usuario?

Tags: linux, ssh

He estado investigando y no encuentro nada, encuentro muchas cosas similares pero no lo que estoy buscando...

(Con imprima me refiero a que lo registre en un txt por ejemplo)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, y la verdad que no plantea un problema específico. Te recomiendo que repases muy bien la sección del [help/on-topic] sobre el tipo de preguntas que se permiten realizar. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las sesiones sshd son registradas por defecto, podría variar de un sistema a otro, pero en Ubuntu, por ejemplo, se almacenan en el fichero `/var/log/auth.log`

Para listar las sesiones que se han abierto:

```
$ grep -e "sshd.*session opened" /var/log/auth.log
```

La salida del comando sería algo como:

```
May 11 11:28:02 pro sshd[16870]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 11 12:44:03 pro sshd[26475]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Por otro lado, si lo que se desea es que se escriba en un fichero específico entonces debemos hacer uso del servicio syslog y configurarlo de la siguiente manera:

> NOTA: Estas indicaciones están probadas en Ubuntu, por lo que los sistemas basados en Ubuntu, como algunas distribuciones de Mint deberían funcionar de forma análoga

En primer lugar editamos la configuración de SSHD (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) y cambiamos el parámetro `SyslogFacility`

```
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
```

Existen varios valores posibles, he elegido LOCAL0 por que no se usa actualmente para ningún otro servicio en mi máquina.

Luego añadimos un nuevo fichero de configuración al directorio `/etc/rsyslog.d`, por ejemplo `myssh_log.conf`, dicho fichero tendrá una única linea:

```
local0.*                         -/var/log/sshd_local.log
```

Otra opción es añadirlo al fichero `/etc/syslog.conf` o `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (dependiendo del que tengas en tu sistema)

Para aplicar los cambios reiniciamos ambos servicios:

```
systemctl restart syslog sshd
```

A partir de este momento todos los accesos por ssh quedarán registrados en el fichero configurado: `/var/log/sshd_local.log`

Comment: En este caso yo estoy en Linux Mint

Comment: Agradezco mucho el curro en responder la pregunta! Pero mi pregunta en realidad es como hacer para registrar yo esa actividad en un fichero que yo decida.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta para escribir en un fichero de log específico

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta, un saludo y gracias de nuevo

Comment: Genial Eneko, sin embargo no has marcado la respuesta como correcta, ¿hay algo que no haya quedado solucionado del todo?, ¿no funciona corectametne en tu sistema?

Comment: Se me olvidó marcarlo, si que me sirvió

Answer (score 0):

En linux tienes el comando "last" indica desde donde se conecto y la hora de la conexión. Y si la quieres en un archivo txt "last > last.txt".